# [Google Sheet]Lookup from the two-dimensional grid

Tags: google-sheets

Because I am using Google Form to collect data. The source of data is not what I want so I need to create a tab and transform the data.

Here is an example of the Google Sheet (Exported from Google Form)

```
Group Leader    Groupmates
Leader 1        John       Mary       Linda
Leader 2        KK         Johanna
Leader 3        Rick
```

I transformed the name grid into an array (first column below). My question is how can I find the corresponding Leader (second column below)?

```
Groupmate  Group Leader
John       Leader 1
Mary       Leader 1
Linda      Leader 1
KK         Leader 2
Johanna    Leader 2
Rick       Leader 3
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I have created this add-on, to help with rearranging google form data for a friend. You can try it [here:](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-splitter/dhaihbfkhlfihidfdedfpaalhppaokbm?utm_source=permalink). Once you run the add-on it will create a sidebar, where you can select which columns you want to combine and make it into a row.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. You will need to change the sheet names and ranges to suit your data needs.It also creates a custom menu to run it from. You could run it on form submit.

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Fix Data', [ 
      { name: 'Fix', functionName: 'reArrange' },
      ]);  
}
function reArrange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")//get data sheet
  var lr = s.getLastRow()  //get last row with data 
  var lc = s.getLastColumn() //get last column with data   
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")//sheet to write to
  var rng = s.getRange(2, 2, lr-1,lc).getValues() 
  var newrng=[]  //new array
  for(var i=0;i<rng.length;i++){ //for each row in range
    for(var j=1;j<rng[0].length;j++){ //for each column in range
      if(rng[i][j]==""){break} //if column is blank break the J loop
        newrng.push([rng[i][j],rng[i][0]]) //push values to new array
     }}
   s1.getRange(2, 1, newrng.length,newrng[0].length).setValues(newrng)//set values in sheet2
 }
```

Comment: Oh my god I thought it is just a simple Sheet formula. Seems App Script is the way to go.

Comment: If this works for you, please approve the answer.Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I haven't try it yet. Will approve it if it works. Thanks